# Flex AS3: How do I load an image dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

What I want to accomplish is load an image in a container. After googling for a while I found that I could use `Loader`. However, the image initially was displayed by a `BitmapImage` element.

The question I have for you is if it's a good way to load an image by initializing a `BitmapImage`, setting the source and adding it to a container or I should go the `Loader way?

**UPDATE:**
This is the code I changed it to to use an `Image`, registered the `READY` event but it is not triggered.

```
protected function loadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
    imageContainer.addElement(attachedImage);
}

protected function loadAttachedImage():void {
    attachedImage = new Image();
    attachedImage.addEventListener(FlexEvent.READY, loadCompleteHandler, false, 0, true);
    attachedImage.source = "assets/images/layouts/bottomAligned.png";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Flex, you should use either `BitmapImage` or `Image`. `Loader` is not a Flex component and should not be used at any time in a Flex application. Loader is the way you download and display an image in a pure-ActionScript project.

Comment: is it a good option to use Loader and put its content into a BitmapImage?

Comment: Why would you? Both `BitmapImage` and `Image` are able to load images from same sources, and several others as well. All you need to do is set the `source` property and it automatically loads it.

Comment: You need to attach the listener directly to the Image, rather than to the `contentLoaderInfo` property like you do with a `Loader`. So `Image.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler)` instead of `Image.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler)`

Comment: I need to know if the image loaded or failed and Image or BitmapImage does not seem to support this

Comment: that is what I am doing but it is not triggering the `COMPLETE` nor the `READY` event. After registering the listener, I should set the `source` right? Then on done, it should trigger `READY` or `COMPLETE`.

Comment: It does support it. Please edit your question with the code you are using. That is the only way I (or anyone else) can figure out what is wrong

Comment: Try setting `useWeakReference` to false and making sure `imageContainer` is actually on the stage. Additionally, use `trace` statements to test whether functions are being run rather than GUI changes. Less to debug that way.